# How to generate Excel/PDF through PHP

Tags: php, html, excel, pdf

I have a table and I want to download the table data as excel/pdf using PHP.

FYKI, below shared the UI, Requesting Help

```html
<strong>Student Name</strong> : Suresh (XII Std)
<br/><br/>
<table width="250" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><strong>Subject</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Mark</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Language</td>
    <td align="center">95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">English</td>
    <td align="center">99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Maths</td>
    <td align="center">100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Total</td>
    <td align="center">294/300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/><br/>Download as 
<input type="button" name="export" value="&darr; Excel"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="export" value="&darr; PDF"/>
```

While click download button I want excel output like below.

[Report Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EdC9.png)

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Have you tried any existing libraries? AFAIK, there are many many libraries out there using which you can implement this functionality. Also, there are many already answered questions on SO which can help you.

Comment: you can used FPDF plugin for Generate dynamic PDF

Comment: if you wan't generate excel file than used PHPExcel Plugin for that

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Plugin, ok i will do.. if any clarification i will revert you

Comment: use [phpgrid](https://phpgrid.com/example/export-datagrid-to-excel-or-html/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a library.

I suggest you use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) for Excel and [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io) for PDF.

Both libraries have good documentation and they can be customized based on your requirements.